# Best practice for storing unique data from multiple oracle queries

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I am using Oraclize to get data from the web, I would like to get some data from a few different sources and store each in a unique variable. What is the best practice and most efficient way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use mappings, they are like arrays which will allow you to add undefined amount of data to your contract.

See http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#mappings

For your situation, you could do the following:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract MappingExample {
    mapping(uint => string) public data;

    function addData(unint index, string newData) {
        data[index] = newData;
    }

    function getData(unint index) {
        return data[index];
    }
}
```